# Python - Sorting Lists By Minimum

Tags: python, arrays, list

I want to sort a list by it's lowest/minimum price ($30), the price is constantly being updated. The list contains other info such as unix timestamp etc.. So the only way i've been able to isolate the price is through a loop.

```
new = [[1548006540000, '30.48000000', '30.50000000', '30.48000000', '30.49000000', '9.44678000', 1548006599999, '288.05801500', 5, '4.24009000', '129.27641360', '0'], 
[1548006600000, '30.50000000', '30.50000000', '30.48000000', '30.49000000', '8.56304000', 1548006659999, '261.12404810', 3, '8.17304000', '249.23684810', '0'], 
[1548006660000, '30.49000000', '30.49000000', '30.48000000', '30.48000000', '14.27839000', 1548006719999, '435.27885450', 7, '14.27547000', '435.18985290', '0'], 
[1548006720000, '30.50000000', '30.57000000', '30.50000000', '30.53000000', '103.97541000', 1548006779999, '3173.52545900', 28, '58.78941000', '1794.71718910', '0'], 
[1548006780000, '30.53000000', '30.59000000', '30.51000000', '30.52000000', '86.32365000', 1548006839999, '2635.32247120', 31, '23.33218000', '712.42226920', '0'], 
[1548006840000, '30.52000000', '30.52000000', '30.38000000', '30.39000000', '618.95322000', 1548006899999, '18842.24179880', 120, '115.54521000', '3516.61937340', '0'], 
[1548006900000, '30.39000000', '30.39000000', '30.36000000', '30.36000000', '62.09526000', 1548006959999, '1885.52106400', 9, '0.00000000', '0.00000000', '0']]



lowest = []

for l in new:
    sts = ','.join(str(e) for e in l)
    splis = sts.split('\n')
    for lin in splis:
        lan = lin.split(',')
        price = lan[3]



        lowest.append(float(price))

        print(lowest)
```

because there are 7 lists inside a list, i get seven loops, the last loop
is the info i need but i can't use the min() function while the loops are happening, how can i get the minimum of the last loop? any other way to do this (lambda)? thank you in advance..

the clarify, the price is in the 4th index of each sublist. the others are not.

Comment: you may want to spend some time getting more comfortable working with lists. You shouldn't have to convert a list to string just to be able to get to a specific index.

Comment: Are you looking to find minimum of last sublist? If so: `min(new[-1])` (assuming all are integers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Takes 3rd value in sublist

```
prices= [i[3] for i in new]
>>> prices
['30.48000000', '30.48000000', '30.48000000', '30.50000000', '30.51000000', '30.38000000', '30.36000000']
```

Or this? I am quite confused what you want

Takes min values out of 1-4th values in sublist

```
prices = [min(i[1:5]) for i in new]
>>> flat_list
['30.48000000', '30.48000000', '30.48000000', '30.50000000', '30.51000000', '30.38000000', '30.36000000']
```

I guess the dataset is classical market api which has 3rd value as min price value in given timeframe right? If this is so, than both solutions are equivalent but faster is the first one

Answer (score 0):

You should use lambda. I didn't understood which index is the price but if that's always in index 3 for example than you need:

```
lowest = min(new, key=lambda x:x[3])
```

this would give you the line with the 3rd element the smallest.
If I misunderstood you please comment and I'll try to help you out.

Comment: so after what i wrote just add [3]:
lowest = min(new, key=lambda x:x[3]) [3]

Answer (score 0):

I have edited your original code:

```
lowest = []

for l in new:
    price = l[3] # get the fourth element from each sublist (index = 3)
    lowest.append(float(price))

min_price = min(lowest) # get the minimum
sorted_list = sorted(lowest) # get the sorted list
```